# How to explicitly log off ftp site using C#?

Tags: c#, ftp, ftp-client, ftpwebrequest

Looking at our the event viewer in our IIS-FTP server and noticed there's a lot of entries in there: "User  at host  has timed-out after 120 seconds of inactivity."

Is there a way to explicitly log off FTP in C# and making the Event Viewer less chatty?

I cannot find anything via search (and on here) and even the code sample from Microsoft doesn't say anything about logging off. Does that mean no one really logs off FTP, just let it go until inactivity kicks the user off?

We more or less borrowed the AsynchronousFtpUpLoader code from here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ftpwebrequest(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: How about setting KeepAlive to false? Does that help?

Comment: I'll try setting that to false.

Comment: The trick is that the code needs to send a "bye" command to the FTP server to have it drop the connection at that time. Most FTP servers will drop the connection after just a few minutes, so leaving a connection hanging isn't much of an issue since it will out-close after a few minutes of no activity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `FtpWebRequest` does not have a **Bye** command built into it. This means the `FtpWebRequest` cannot send a "bye" (quit/close) request. This isn't an issue for most usage. FTP servers typically drop any connection that has been inactive for more than 2 minutes.